# Why is JSF better than Struts for Portlet Development?

Tags: jsf, struts, jsr168

Someone said to me that JSF is better at sharing information within the context, but Struts 1.1 can't.

In JSR168, If we need to develop a Portlet then sharing information in the context is critical. Therefore,JSF seems to be the better option.

My question is *what is sharing information within context*?

Does that mean that different application deployed in the same container can share date?

Or what other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to meet your question, but in my understanding you can use the BackingBeans to share information, if the scope is well-defined. And of course you've got the `FacesContext` to exchange information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, in portlet FacesContext will be able to share information within a portlet application and not between portlet application.
to share data between different portlet application, you have use some other techniques like
dynacache in ibm portal or any portal specific technology.